# Merging sheets of excel using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to take data of two sheets and comparing with each other if it matches i want to append column. Let me explain this by showing what i am doing and what i am trying to get in output using python.

This is my sheet1 from excel.xlsx:
[image: sheet1]

it contains four column name,class,age and group.

This is my sheet2 from excel.xlsx:
[image: sheet2]

it contains default, and name column with extra names in it.

So, Now i am trying to match name of sheet2 with sheet1, if the name containing in sheet1 matches with sheet2 then i want to add default value corresponding to that name from sheet2.

This i need in output:
[image: output]

As you can see only Ravi and Neha having default in sheet2 and that name matches with sheet1 name. Suhash and Aish dont have any default value so not anything coming there.

This code i tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

df1 = pd.read_excel('stack.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1') 
df2 = pd.read_excel('stack.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2') 



df1['DEFAULT'] = df1.NAME.map(df2.set_index('NAME')['DEFAULT'].to_dict())


df1.to_excel('play.xlsx',index=False)
```

and getting output excel like this:

[image]

Not getting default against Ravi.

Please help me with this to get this expected output using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you read each sheet into a dataframe (df = sheet1, df2 = sheet2)
it's quite easy and there are a few options (ranked in order of speed, from fastest to slowest):

```
# .merge
df = df.merge(df2, how='left', on='Name')

# pd.conact
df = pd.concat([df.set_index('Name'), df2.set_index('Name').Default], axis=1, sort='Name', join='inner')

# .join
df = df.set_index('Name').join(df2.set_index('Name'))

# .map
df.Default = df.Name.map(df2.set_index('Name')['Default'].to_dict())
```

All of them will have the following output:

```
    Name  Default  Class  Age Group
0    NaN      NaN      4    2   tig
1   Ravi      2.0      5    5  rose
2    NaN      NaN      3    3  lily
3  Suhas      NaN      5    5  rose
4    NaN      NaN      2    2   sun
5   Neha      3.0      5    5  rose
6    NaN      NaN      5    2   sun
7   Aish      NaN      5    5  rose
```

Then you overwrite the original sheet by using `df.to_excel`

**EDIT**

So the code you shared has 3 problems. One of which seems to be a language barrier... You only need **1** of the options I gave you. Secondly there's a missing ' when reading the first sheet into `df`. And lastly you're inconsistent when using the df names. you defined `df1` and `df2` but used just `df` in the code which doesn't work
 So the correct code would be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

df1 = pd.read_excel('stack.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1') #Here the ' was missing
df2 = pd.read_excel('stack.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2') 


## Now you chose one of the options, I used map here, but you can pick any one of them

df1.DEFAULT = df1.NAME.map(df2.set_index('NAME')['DEFAULT'].to_dict())


df1.to_excel('play.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merging_default.py", line 16, in <module>
    df = df.set_index('NAME').join(df2.set_index('NAME'))
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4178, in set_index
    level = frame[col]._values
   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 153, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 170, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer
KeyError: 'NAME'

Comment: getting error like this while i am trying to execute this

Comment: @srish Yup makes sense,you mispelled the key. Whenever adressing a key in a DataFrame you need to type it *exactly* the same. In your example your excel sheet header was 'Name' so if you write 'NAME' it won't work

Comment: File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 833, in _get_merge_keys
    right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1706, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Name'

Comment: Now i am able to execute, but default column coming blank and name column not coming and others are coming in descending order.

Comment: actually i need output whether it is merge or join.

Comment: @srish So I basically wrote it for you now. If that doesn't work I'm out of my depth.

Comment: merging_default.py:9: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  df1.DEFAULT = df1.NAME.map(df2.set_index('NAME')['DEFAULT'].to_dict())

Comment: @srish a) that's a user warning not an error so it may still have run, so did you check the output file? b) you get that error because the `DEFAULT` column is not in your first sheet, which IMO it should be. If for some reason you don't want that you have to write it like so `df1['DEFAULT'] = df1.NAME.map(df2.set_index('NAME')['DEFAULT'].to_dict())` . Also please user code formatting in you comments as well.

Comment: Hey its working just now i am not getting default against Ravi.. I edited my question with modification you provided.

Comment: Please help with that one.

Comment: @srish as with the key, chances are that you have a trailing whitespace in one of the sheets. So it's `'Ravi '` in one and `'Ravi'` in the other. Also please mark the answer as accepted, because it did answer you question and consider upvoting it if you found it helpful

Comment: i checked that.. there is no any trailing whitespace, they are exact same.